# Highlight Overlap Days Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem to solve to increase the speed at which the code performs the task.

I have a table with names of Hire Cars and two dates - From and To. I need to go through the range (say 10k rows) check and highlight all overlapping dates.

No   Hire Car    From        To

1    ABC         01 Jan 12   12 Jan 12
2    ABC         14 Jan 12   15 Jan 12
3    ABC         25 Jan 12   02 Feb 12
4    DEF         01 Jan 12   12 Jan 12
5    DEF         12 Jan 12   02 Feb 12
6    DEF         14 Jan 12   15 Jan 12

For hire car DEF there are overlapping days, double counting in fact which i need to be able to highlight so that the user can quickly identify and correct.

This is the code that I have developed. The problem is that if you have a Range of 10k Rows it is extremely slow.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate with Office/Excel 2010

```
    Function CheckOverlap(StartLine, EndLine, StartColumn)

Dim i As Integer, y As Integer
Dim DateToCompare
Dim HireCar
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response

'Check StartDate Column
For i = StartLine To EndLine

    DateToCompare = Cells(i, StartColumn)
    HireCar = Cells(i, 2)
    For y = StartLine To EndLine
        'If we are at the same line with DateToCompare cell then we should not perform any check
        If i <> y Then    
            If DateToCompare >= Cells(y, StartColumn) And DateToCompare <= Cells(y, StartColumn + 1) And HireCar = Cells(y, 2) Then
                'We should highlight both cells that contain overlapping dates
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, StartColumn).Interior.Color = 5296274
                ActiveSheet.Cells(y, StartColumn).Interior.Color = 5296274
            End If
        End If
    Next y
Next i

HireCar = 0

'Check EndDate Column
For i = StartLine To EndLine

    DateToCompare = Cells(i, StartColumn + 1)
    HireCar = Cells(i, StartColumn - 1)
    For y = StartLine To EndLine
        'If we are at the same line with DateToCompare cell then we should not perform any check
        If i <> y Then    
            If DateToCompare >= Cells(y, StartColumn) And DateToCompare <= Cells(y, StartColumn + 1) And HireCar = Cells(y, StartColumn - 1) Then
                'We should highlight both cells that contain overlapping dates
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, StartColumn + 1).Interior.Color = 5296274
                ActiveSheet.Cells(y, StartColumn + 1).Interior.Color = 5296274
            End If
        End If
    Next y
Next i


'Last check: If the starting and ending date are the same
For i = StartLine To EndLine
    If Cells(i, StartColumn) - Cells(i, StartColumn + 1) = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, StartColumn).Interior.Color = 5296274
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, StartColumn + 1).Interior.Color = 5296274
    End If
Next i

' If there are no Overlap Days in Database skip filtering
' StartDate and EndDate Column
' Count Cells with Interior.Color = 5296274 (Green Colour)
Count = 0

For i = StartLine To EndLine
    If Cells(i, StartColumn).Interior.Color = 5296274 Then
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Next i

' Msg if Database has no Overlap Days
Msg = "Validation check completed. There are 'NO' Overlap Days"
Style = vbOKOnly
Title = "Cash Flow"

' Require on Error Resume Next in case Database is NOT filtered
On Error Resume Next
If Count = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
    Exit Function
Else
    Call Filter_Colour
End If

MsgBox "Any Green highlights indicate Overlap Days"
```

End Function

Comment: `1.` From the sample data you have given, can you show what a proper overlapt date for a car? `DEF 01 Jan 12 12 Jan 12` hire ends on 12th Jan. And starting another hire on 12th Jan. Is that an Overlap? `2.` Do you only want to get overlap dates for each car?

Comment: Yes DEF 12 Jan 12 needs to be considered as an overlap. In effect what I need to count is only complete days.

Comment: OKay, What do you mean by a *complete days* ?

Comment: complete 24 hour days - i.e. 12 Jan 12 is a single day so if user enters 12 Jan 12 to 14 Jan 12 and the next period starts with 12 Jan 12 he is double counting 12 Jan 12.

Comment: Please do take a look at the sample code I posted. In my understanding, If end date of previous booking is equivalent to start date of next booking, then it's an overlap for a car... so confirm and comment after you try this out..

Answer (score 0):

The fastest approach would be to sort the table (first order: cars, second order: from-date)

Then for each line:
there is a collision iif the line above is the same car and the to-date from above is larger than the from-date of the current line.

You can do these steps either with VBA or Excel-Formulas.

Comment: I need to do this with VBA

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algo to show you a blank when there's an overlap on the latter rows. To run this, it's strictly assumed that your CAR column is sorted as per sample shown in the question.

```
Option Explicit

'-- assuming the CAR names column is sorted
'-- so each car block in one place
'-- run on button click event

Sub FindOverlaps()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim vInput As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets(2).Range("B2:E7")
vInput = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng))

For i = LBound(vInput) To UBound(vInput) - 1
    For j = LBound(vInput) + 1 To UBound(vInput)
        If vInput(i, 2) = vInput(j, 2) Then
            If vInput(i, 4) = vInput(j, 3) Then
                vInput(j, 3) = ""
                vInput(j, 4) = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

rng.Offset(0, 6).Resize(UBound(vInput), UBound(Application.Transpose(vInput))) = vInput

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT AS PER OP'S COMMENT

1. Transpose the sorted data into the **same range** as per input data, so remove `offset(0,4)`:
2. Add `conditiona formatting` to highlight anyrow that's null within the specified range. (otherwise entire sheet will be coloured where empty cells are)

Code changes:

```
rng.Offset(0, 6).FormatConditions.Delete
rng.Offset(0, 6).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="="""""
rng.Offset(0, 6).FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
```

Comment: The algo takes `dates seraial number` to do the validation. So when you are outputting you may need to manage the `dateformat` in the Overlaps columns.. You may also change the code to show only the overlaps :) if you wish to. So all the other cells will be blank. Performance wise this will be a powerboost compared to iterating through cells and inserting a function multiple times..

Comment: I have tried this but it throws a Runtime Error 9 at this line - If vInput(i, 4) = vInput(j, 3) Then - This idea will certainly give a power boost compared to what I have designed.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The code runs fine, my apologies. Can you give me a little additional help. I do not need to transpose to another range. What I need to do is simply highlight the overlap 'block' as you show above i.e. 1 Jan 12 to 12 Jan 12 and 12 Jan 12 to 02 Feb 12, in yellow.

Comment: @sglxl =) glad you got it worked. I am not transposing to another sheet. It's the rows next to it. I am doing an update to colour the rows in that range only. Take a look at it.

Comment: I have tried this again on a range of 12K rows. There is a problem with overlaps if you put the same CAR with the same days in two continuous rows. i.e. 1 DEF 1 Jan 12 to 5 Jan 12 in Row 2 and then 1 DEF 1 Jan 12 to 5 Jan 12 in Row 3. This is not picked up as an overlap or double counting. Over 12k rows it is slow again but I cannot see ho it can be made to go any faster. I guess if you do not have to write to a separate range but merely highlight existing range  this will speed it up.

Comment: That's because I am using the same array to do the erasing of the overlaps. But good point. Let me add that code piece as well. Looking at your sample I didn't assume you will have duplicates as well. Why don't you indicate all your rules that you want to apply? The code is not writing to another range ONE BY ONE CELL.. so it is not a matter on perfomrance. It's a quick dump.

Comment: My apologies for not being explicit. This is my first posting so will improve.